# How to find error in this file ? Only cross sign is showing on the project file but below the project file, there is nothing red mark showing

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, web-applications

This is the links .
Only cross sign is showing on the project file but below the project file, there is nothing red mark showing.

https://ibb.co/Zm8DMSJ

This is the error which I am facing after enter the details..
This is the project using hibernate . This is web app project
https://ibb.co/4FQmBML

Comment: Look in the Problems view

Comment: What greg-449 says. Instead of using Java 5 (which is the default of Maven, but pretty old and rarely used nowadays) in your project, you probably want to specify the Java version in your `pom.xml`, e.g. via `<properties><maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source><maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target></properties>`.